# Emulator recording crashes when I try to record with mp4

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to record my emulator and for some reason it is only willing to record on webm. Whenever I untick the `Use emulator record (WebM)`, the recording crashes with error
`Failed to record the screen - Screen recording terminated with exit code 218`

I have restarted android studio a couple times